# map rows of one column to the data of those rows in other dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which has the following data:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|         City|      Country|
+-------------+-------------+
|    Vancouver|       Canada|
|     Portland|United States|
|San Francisco|United States|
|      Seattle|United States|
|  Los Angeles|United States|
|    San Diego|United States|
|    Las Vegas|United States|
```

and so on... And I have another dataframe which has rows of the cities as columns. I have 37 columns i.e. 37 cities. Like this:

datetime,Vancouver,Portland,San Francisco,Seattle,Los Angeles,San Diego,Las Vegas,...
2012-10-01 13:00:00,0.0,0.0,150.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,360.0,...
2012-10-01 14:00:00,76.0,80.0,87.0,80.0,88.0,81.0,21.0,23.0,49.0,62.0,92.0,

For the 1st dataframe, I converted dataframe to map

val array = citydf1.collect.map(r => Map(citydf.columns.zip(r.toSeq):_*)).foreach(println)

Map(City -> Vancouver, Country -> Canada), Map(City -> Portland, Country -> United States),Map(City -> San Francisco, Country -> United States)

I want to do aggregate functions like min, max, avg, count on the columns in the 2nd dataframe,
can I join the values of the map to those columns so that I don't have to write query for all the 37 columns? If it is possible..

Comment: Can you share what the join of these 2 dataframes should give according to you? And what did you try so far?

Comment: Also i am assuming  the second dataframe include just one row ? Else how would you map it? based on time given? If it includes just one row you can use a map(kind of enum) instead of. data frame and then use withcolumn and add the value to the first dataframe